# Groovy: Dynamic nested properties

Tags: grails, dynamic, groovy, properties, chain

I have a chain of properties that I may need to access. For example:

- device.room
- device.room.usageArea
- ...
- device.room.usageArea.floor.building.account

I know that I can get a property with a dynamic string in the way `device."${property}"`, ***but it doesn't work for a deep nesting***.

How can I dynamically access to the account property, with a string chain given (such as `properties = device."room.usageArea.floor.building.account"`)

**Edit**

I tried a way that is working, but I'm not proud of it:

```
Eval.me 'device', device, "device.${properties}"
```

*where `properties` is a string with dot-separated properties*

Comment: It is not the same as the existing question. This is about *chained* properties. I edited the post modifying the name `property` to `properties` to be clearer.

Comment: Did you look at the answer? It works for nested instances (e.g. chained properties as you call them).